# Creating a New Local User Account in W10 using Powershell but doesn't populate front end

Tags: powershell, windows-10, local, user-accounts

I am attempting to make a new local user account working on my actual host machine through the administrator powershell terminal page. I ran the code below successfully and saw the account populate the computer management>User page but I was not able to select my new account through the lock screen nor through the start>account page neither. I tried restarting the host machine, but there was still no option to sign in as this new user through start menu account options, ctrl alt delete nor switch user.

@Community, Do you have any modifications you would make to these commands listed below to make the new user account populate to the front end to be selectable to log in through the user sign in page?

'''

```
PS>$Password = Read-Host -AsSecureString

PS>New-LocalUser -AccountNeverExpires -Description "Test" -FullName "John Smith" -Name john.smith - 
Password $Password -Confirm
```

'''

Any help will be appreciated - thanks.

Comment: I assume `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\SpecialAccounts\UserList\john.smith` wasn't previously created to hide the account from the login screen?

Comment: Thanks for replying. No I did not do the action you listed above. I only ran the commands I listed in the question and checked the computer management>User page.

Comment: Is this a domain or standalone machine?  If you use the same command to create a user without a `.` in the name does that show on the login screen?

Comment: This is a standalone virtual W10 machine. I tested it with this query:

'''
    New-LocalUser -AccountNeverExpires -Description "Test" -FullName "Test Test" 
   -Name TestTest -Password $Password -Confirm


'''

However, the user account still does not appear within the user accounts in control panel and is not selectable in the login screen. 

Please let me know if I can supply you with any other information. Thanks for your help.

*** PS the spacing of the command above got weird in the comment but there are no additional spaces ***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

John.Smith must be member of at least one local group.
Put him in "Users" group, it will appear at the logon screen.

Comment: Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Users" -Member "John.Smith"

Answer (score 0):

@Christophe, Success!! Yes thank you! Awesome! I can now see the user john.smith as a selectable user to login at the windows start up screen and all other account screens.

Much appreciated! Here is the commands to create a new user using powershell as a whole with @Christophe's answer included. Thanks again! FYI there are no odd spaces in solutions below I just can't get them all on one line in a comment.

'''

```
PS>$Password = Read-Host -AsSecureString

PS>New-LocalUser -AccountNeverExpires -Description "Test" 
-FullName "John Smith" -Name john.smith 
-Password $Password -Confirm

PS>Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Users" -Member "John.Smith"
```

'''